# How to control app authorization flow?

Tags: facebook, authorization

I started using the new Authorization system for apps.

I seem to be experiencing a problem where Facebook sends the user to the authorization dialog whether I tell it to or not. This presents a problem to me about how to make public pages, ones that should be available to people who haven't authorized the app.

Even if I kill the app almost immediately in the PHP code, it still sends the user.

Any way to make it so I can not require authorization?

Comment: can you show your code, the parts that are doing the auth. edit your question and add the code, btw.

Comment: This is about authorization flow, not merely code, but is still developer related and related to Facebook. The problem is that it doesn't require ANY code to get to the "allow application" dialog. Even if I use a blank file it still asks me to authorize the app, because Facebook just knows I haven't authorized the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Switch Referrals off.

Answer (score 0):

I've always have excellent luck with FB.getLoginStatus()

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

It can tell you immediately what state the user is in, and you can either send them to be logged in, or send them to a screen that is for logged in users.

Comment: Thanks, but, basically, the callback page could be empty for all Facebook cares, it would still send the user to an authorization page -- no control from the actual code, that's the problem.

Comment: It did not. But I have found the solution. Authenticated referrals caused me to lose any code based control to authentication.

Comment: So getLoginStatus() doesn't return correctly for authenticated referrals?  Ouch!  That's bad.  You should log a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs.

Comment: No, I didn't even use it. The problem was that I was being sent to the "allow this app" page without telling it to from code. It could've been a plank PHP file for all Facebook cared, it just knew the user hadn't allowed the app. Once I turned off referrals, I got back control of the authentication, and could tell my code to redirect them to the "allow the app" dialog.

Comment: Could you please close this question since you got it figured out?